# Dataflow: Accessing a value provider after the pipeline is complete

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm attempting to do a lagging update after my pipeline completes where the tables are passed in at runtime due to date versioning. Being this code is executed as a template, that requires the use of nestedValueProviders.

```
public interface DataQueryRunnerOptions extends DataflowPipelineOptions {

@Description("Table to read/write payload data.")
    @Default.String("test.payloadData")
    ValueProvider<String> getPayloadTable();

@Description("Table to read eligibility data from, and update with payloadData")
    @Default.String("test.dqr_test_eligibilities")
    ValueProvider<String> getEligibilityInputTable();

}
```

Usage in pipeline:

```
campaignIdToDataQueryMap.apply("RunDataQueries", ParDo.of(new RunDataQueries()))
      .apply("WritePayloadDataToTable", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
        .withSchema(getPayloadDataSchema())
        .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
        .to(options.getPayloadTable()));
```

Then I invoke code after the pipeline:

```
pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();

runFinalUpdate(options);
```

For the runFinalUpdate method:

```
private static void runFinalUpdate(DataQueryRunner2Options options) {

    ValueProvider.NestedValueProvider eligTable = ValueProvider.NestedValueProvider.of(
      options.getEligibilityInputTable(),
      (SerializableFunction<String, String>) eligibilityInputTable -> options.getEligibilityInputTable().get()
    );

    ValueProvider.NestedValueProvider payloadTable = ValueProvider.NestedValueProvider.of(
      options.getPayloadTable(),
      (SerializableFunction<String, String>) payload -> options.getPayloadTable().get()
    );

    String finalUpdate = "UPDATE " + eligTable.get() + " elig SET elig.dataQueryPayload = (SELECT pd.dataQueryPayload FROM `"
      + payloadTable.get() + "` pd WHERE pd.numericId = elig.numericId and pd.campaignId = elig.campaignId)"
      + " WHERE elig.dataQueryPayload IS NULL";

    try {
      Utilities.runQuery(finalUpdate);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      LOG.error("Final update failure: " + e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

This gives the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Value only available at runtime, but accessed from a non-runtime context: RuntimeValueProvider{propertyName=eligibilityInputTable, default=test.dqr_test_eligibilities}
```

How can I access this value outside of my pipeline run? Is there a better way to do "once only" work after a pipeline is complete?

Comment: Why not creating it inside the pipeline? Is it must be at the end? Can it be in last step in the pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ValueProvider interface allows pipelines to accept runtime parameters. In order to access these values for reporting / logging purposes you need to access them within the Beam DAG. A potential solution for this is to create a reporting branch in your pipeline which takes a single dummy value and within a DoFn that 'processes' this dummy value export the options to an external store.

Java (SDK 2.9.0):

```
public interface YourOptions extends PipelineOptions {
 @Description("Your option")
 @Default.String("Hello World!")
 ValueProvider<String> getStringValue();

 void setStringValue(ValueProvider<String>  value);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

 // Create pipeline
 YourOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation()
     .as(YourOptions.class);

 Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

 // Branch for pushing the Value Provider value

 p.apply(Create.of(1)).apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<Integer, Integer>() {

   @ProcessElement public void process(ProcessContext c) {

     YourOptions ops = c.getPipelineOptions().as(YourOptions.class);
     // Do something like push to DB here....
     LOG.info("Option StringValue was {}" , ops.getStringValue());

   }
 }));

 // The main pipeline....
 p.apply(Create.of(1,2,3,4)).apply(Sum.integersGlobally());

 p.run();
}
```